# Erro 500 ao carregar demais a página

Tags: php, json, servidor

Tem um cliente que vende imóveis e os dados dos imóveis é pego de um link jSON externo. O sistema está funcionando, só que o sistema demora pois são MUITOS dados. Ele passa mais ou menos 1 - 2 minutos carregando e depois informa um erro 500 (internal server error). Uso um servidor VPS de 2GB de RAM.

Comment: Esse código 500 geralmente indica um erro de programação ou permissões incorretas para *pastas/arquivos*, coloque no início do seu código: `ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`, verifique novamente e veja se aparecem erros mais especificos, verifique também o *log* de mensagem em `/var/log/message`.